# How to do a reinterpret_cast with Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c

**Edit:** I am looking for `reinterpret_cast`in Objective-C so the following is meaningless for my intended question.

> Are there static casts in Objective-C?
>
> e.g. in this C++ example `static_cast` is used for a good reason:
>
> ```
> float rnd = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
> ```
>
> I can think of using a `union` or pointers to directly access the
>   integer value as a float but that would make the code much more
>   complex.
>
> How would I do the same thing as in the C++ example conveniently in
>   Objective-C?

Comment: A `union` does not perform a static cast to convert your `float` into an `int`.

Comment: You write `static_cast` but your comment about `union` suggests you might be thinking `reinterpret_cast`. Can you clarify and state what you think the semantics of your expression are?

Comment: You are right, I was looking for `reinterpret_cast`. I am sorry for the misconception.

Comment: And why does you example go anyway near reinterpret_cast - the answer will probably be the same as use a plain C cast

Comment: I was confusing both and made the wrong conclusions.

Comment: This question is now in a very bad state I would revert to the static cast which was a good question and create a new one with example code foir reinterpret cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the clarification you are after `reinterpret_cast`:

You are correct you can do it with a `union`. If you want to do it inline you can use a cast, address-of and indirection...

The C-style cast `(type)expr` in both (Objective-)C and C++ works similarly: if the equivalent of a `static_cast` is appropriate it does that, e.g. between `int` and `float` and other value types; otherwise it will do the equivalent of a `reinterpret_cast`, e.g. between pointer-types.

So you just need to convert to a pointer, cast, and indirect. E.g.:

```
int z = 0xDEADBEEF;
float y = *(float *)&z;
NSLog(@"%d -> %f", z, y);
```

Yes it's a bit ugly, but then what you are doing is as well ;-) To make it a bit nicer define it as a macro:

```
#define REINTERPRET(type, expr) (*(type *)&(expr))
```

which you can use as:

```
int z = 0xDEADBEEF;
float y = REINTERPRET(float, z);
NSLog(@"%d -> %f", z, y);
```

As with `reinterpret_cast`, you should use this sparingly and with care!

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much. As this functionality does not seem to be directly implemented in Objective-C your solution is the best I could get.

Answer (score 2):

Objective C is a superset of C so do this the C way and simple casts

```
float rnd = (float) (rand()) / (float)(RAND_MAX);
```

Comment: @KugelnMMXVI - in what way is it not doing the same thing?

Comment: I don't think you need that many casts.  `(float)(rand()) / (RAND_MAX)` should work as intended.

Comment: @JAL correect nut I decided to use the same casts as in the question which only needs the one static_cast for the same reason