# Lint error objectiveC

Tags: objective-c, lint

I have a linting error on my objC but I don't know how to resolve it, if I'm using the *reinterpret_cast* syntax, the app does not build anymore... Someone has an idea please?

error: NSString+EXT.h:9:  Using C-style cast.  Use reinterpret_cast(...) instead  [readability/casting]

NSString+EXT.h

```
#ifndef ATOM_BROWSER_UI_COCOA_NSSTRING_ANSI_H_
#define ATOM_BROWSER_UI_COCOA_NSSTRING_ANSI_H_

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString(ANSI)

- (BOOL)containsANSICodes;
- (NSMutableAttributedString*)attributedStringParsingANSICodes;

@end

#endif  // ATOM_BROWSER_UI_COCOA_NSSTRING_ANSI_H_
```

Comment: Did you check that the source is compiled as Objective-C source? (And not C source.) Did you try a different name for the category instead of ANSI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple research and test, I fix the issue by following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866352/how-to-do-a-reinterpret-cast-with-obj-c)

A macro like

```ObjC
#define REINTERPRET(type, expr) (*(type *)&(expr))
```

help me to refactorize and resolve the issue